# How to notify UI about action done in API?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, c#-6.0

I'm writing a simple game, like tic tac toe (only mine is bigger). The game play is simple: my turn, check if won, bot's turn, check if won. I have simple `UI` and `API` that uses `Domain Entites` (that's not important now). So when user's moves, API will update the board, will know that next move is bot's move, so will do it and... has to notify UI. Here is my problem.

My question is:
**How to notify UI about bot's move?** I mean, to keep it simple but stick to the best programming practices.

My first thought was to create an event in GameAPI class. Is that good idea? Today will all new stuff, C# 6, etc.. I'm not sure:/ Right now UI is `WinForms`, but I would like to use this API in other UIs, like WPF or even mobile. Here is my simplified code of UI:

**EDIT:** Right now I'm talking about single player game. Both UI and API is a Client. There will be multiplayer through central server in next step, but right now, single player.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private GameAPI api;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        api = new GameAPI();
    }

    private void boardClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Field field = GetClickedField(e);

        MoveResult result = api.MakeMove(clickedColumn);
        if (result != null && result.Row >= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(result.Row + "," + clickedColumn);
            if (result.IsConnected)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Success!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and API:

```
public class GameAPI
{
    public IGame CurrentGame { get; set; }

    public void CreateGame(GameType type)
    {
        CurrentGame = new SinglePlayerGame();
    }

    public Result Move(int column)
    {
        if (CurrentGame == null) return null;

        Player player = CurrentGame.GetNextPlayer();

        if (player.Type == PlayerType.Human) return CurrentGame.Move(column, player.Id);
    }

    public Result MoveBot()
    {
        // Simulate Bot's move...
    }
}
```

Comment: "Best" - unless you define your criteria for "better" it is not possible to answer your question in a manner that produce quality SO answer. Even if you narrow down what exactly you want to improve/prioritize it still likely be "primarily opinion based" post. I'd recommend to stick with "the best as I get it working and finished what I want" :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Best you know, I meant. Solution has to works + it has to be considered as "good programming":) I'll change the topic so it will not be flagged, "just to be flagged".

Comment: .NET 4.5+ provides the [IProgress<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and the [Progress<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx)  implementation class for such scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first thought was to create an event in GameAPI class. Is that good idea?

Yes, why not? Let take for example the modern UI frameworks data binding. The key point of making data binging work is providing a property change notification (read - event) when some property value of the object is modified. Usually that's implemented via `IPropertyNotifyChanged` interface, which is simply a polymorphic way of declaring support for `PropertyChanged` **event**. This way, if you set the object property via code, the UI updates automatically. Hope you see the similarity with your case - the API does something and raises an event, UI (being attached handler to that event as some earlier point) receives the event and updates accordingly.